# How to fill-up cells within a Excel worksheet from a VBA function?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, formula

I simply want to fill-up cells in my spreadsheet from a VBA function. By example, I would like to type =FillHere() in a cell, and in result I will have a few cells filled-up with some data.

I tried with such a function:

```
Function FillHere()
  Dim rngCaller As Range
  Set rngCaller = Application.Caller
  rngCaller.Cells(1, 1) = "HELLO"
  rngCaller.Cells(1, 2) = "WORLD"
End Function
```

It breaks as soon as I try to modify the range. Then I tried this (even it's not really the behavior I'm looking for):

```
Function FillHere()
    Dim rngCaller As Range
    Cells(1, 1) = "HELLO"
    Cells(1, 2) = "WORLD"
End Function
```

This is not working neither. **But it works if I start this function from VBA using F5!** It seems it's not possible to modify anything on the spreadsheet while calling a function... some libraries do that though...

I also tried (in fact it was my first idea) to return a array from the function. The problem is that I only get the first element in the array (there is a trick that implies to select a whole area with the formula at the top left corner + F2 + CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER, but that means the user needs to know by advance the size of the array).

I'm really stuck with this problem. I'm not the final end-user so I need something very easy to use, with, preferably, no argument at all.

PS: I'm sorry I asked this question already, but I wasn't registered at that time and it seems that I can't participate to the other thread anymore.

Comment: Your current approach assumes that there are always *at least two* cells selected, horizontally. The function fails if they are selected vertically, for example. May I ask what you are *actually* trying to do with the function? This info might be helpful.

Comment: This function would return an "unknown" size (both in rows and columns) of data. By example it could be a SQL request again a table in a DB. It would return the name of the columns + the associated rows.

Comment: So basically, starting from the cell the user is currently in, you want to fill some data down and left?

Comment: Exactly!
Like any of these libraries that provide functions to get data from any kind of sources.

Comment: Just write it as a normal VBA function, called via Tools > Macros and use Application.ActiveCell to determine where to put the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do this in two steps:

Change your module to be something like:

```
Dim lastCall As Variant
Dim lastOutput() As Variant

Function FillHere()
    Dim outputArray() As Variant
    ReDim outputArray(1 To 1, 1 To 2)
    outputArray(1, 1) = "HELLO"
    outputArray(1, 2) = "WORLD"

    lastOutput = outputArray
    Set lastCall = Application.Caller

    FillHere = outputArray(1, 1)
End Function

Public Sub WriteBack()
    If IsEmpty(lastCall) Then Exit Sub
    If lastCall Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For i = 1 To UBound(lastOutput, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(lastOutput, 2)
            If (i <> 1 Or j <> 1) Then
                lastCall.Cells(i, j).Value = lastOutput(i, j)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Set lastCall = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then in order to call the Sub go into the ThisWorkbook area in VBA and add something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call WriteBack
End Sub
```

What this does is return the value of the topleft cell and then after calculation completes populates the rest. The way I wrote this it assumes only one FillHere function will be called at a time. If you want to have multiple ones which recalculate at the same time then you will need a more complicated set of global variables.

One word of warning is that this will not care what it overwrites when it populates the other cells.

Edit:
If you want to do this on a Application wide basis in an XLA. The code for the ThisWorkbook area should be something like:

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call WriteBack
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

This will wire up the Application Level calculation.

Comment: Interesting solution, and using a Dictionary to be able to track more than one formula could be neat. But my problem is still the same: I cannot ask the user to add such a code in its spreadsheet's VBA. It would be perfect if I could handle the SheetCalculate Event directly from the module... but that's impossible :(

Comment: Is your code in XLA AddIn? Have Editted response to have a method which would work over an application. Still built for 1 call at a time.

Comment: I didn't know we would do that, that's interesting. But this way it will override the Worksheet's SheetCalculate method no?

Comment: The VBA goes into the XLA and is called once the application completes calculation of any sheet. 

This doesnt override the WorkSheet_SheetCalculate but is called after the WorkSheets one. One slight enhancement you make is to check that the callback range is actually in the sheet that calculated so you only do it as needed.

This is similar to the way I have done this in the past, but mine event handler was hosted in a C# COM AddIn and this worked well.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do won't work in Excel - this is by design.

You *can* do this, though:

```
Function FillHere()
    Redim outputArray(1 To 1, 1 To 2)
    outputArray(1, 1) = "HELLO"
    outputArray(1, 2) = "WORLD"
    FillHere = outputArray
End Function
```

If you then select two adjacent cells in your worksheet, enter `=FillHere()` and press Control+Shift+Enter (to apply as an array formula) then you should see your desired output.

Comment: I know I can do this but the problem is that we cannot know by advance the length of the returned array. I therefore cannot ask the end-user to perform tests until it found the perfect range size. I'm sure there is a way though, cause there are libraries (especially market access libraries) that perform this task very well.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, a function can only affect the cell it is called from.  It sounds like you may need to look at using the [`Worksheet_Change` or `Worksheet_SelectionChange` events](http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm#change) to trigger the modification of cells in the intended range.

Comment: The end-user will insert my module in his spreadsheets, and I cannot ask him to add VBA code anywhere. Maybe there is a way to register the SelectionChange event from the function, but I doubt it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this indirectly using a 2-stage process:
Write your UDF so that it stores data in a sufficiently persistent way (for example global arrrays).
then have an Addin that contains application events that fire after each calculation event, looks at any data stored by the UDFs and then rewrites the neccessary cells (with warning messages about overwrite if appropriate) and reset the stored data.

This way the user does not need to have any code in their workbook.

I think (but do not know for sure) that this is the technique used by Bloomberg etc.

Comment: What is a sufficiently persistent way? In UDF I was only able to use statics... but it's not accessible by anything else. Or is it possible to have a Singleton class in VBA? I'll try.
Bloomberg use a COM library, and it seems that you can do whatever you want with the Excel COM object, except with VBA. So the function can really do everything (and most important, be updated realtime).