# Issue Creating Autofill Macro with a VBA Function

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue creating a macro that will autofill a VBA function named "FindMyOrderNumber". Every time I run a macro to Autofill "FindMyOrderNumber" only the first cell in the column is populated.

This function will look up an order number in column A (A1) and return the name of the worksheet it can be found B (B1).

```
Option Explicit
Function FindMyOrderNumber(strOrder As String) As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.CodeName <> "Sheet3" Then
            Set rng = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = ws.Cells.Find(What:=strOrder, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                FindMyOrderNumber = ws.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

End Function
```

I created this macro to enter my VBA function "=findmyordernumber(a1)" in cell B1 then to Autofill column B.

```
Sub AutofillVBAFunction()

    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=FindMyOrderNumber(RC[-1])"
    Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("B1:B68")
    Range("B1:B68").Select
End Sub
```

After I run this macro only B1 is populated.

Sorry if this has been discussed I am new and I tried [How to fill-up cells within a Excel worksheet from a VBA function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847301/how-to-fill-up-cells-within-a-excel-worksheet-from-a-vba-function) and other questions and I could not apply it to my issue.

Please help

Comment: `Range("B1:B68")="=FindMyOrderNumber(RC[-1])"`  try it.

Comment: @Davesexcel Sounds like an answer to me, if you can also explain why their current code isn't working that would make an excellent one at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add application.volatile to the function, that way it will calculate as the sheet changes.

```
Function FindMyOrderNumber(strOrder As String) As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Application.Volatile
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.CodeName <> "Sheet3" Then
            Set rng = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = ws.Cells.Find(What:=strOrder, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                FindMyOrderNumber = ws.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

End Function
```

It also wouldn't hurt to calculate the sheet when You add the formula to the range.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(Rws, 2))
    Rng = "=FindMyOrderNumber(RC[-1])"
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem that  I am having now is that column A will grow larger past over time I tried using:  
    Range("B:B") = "=FindMyOrderNumber(RC[-1])"  - to cover my bases but then my Excel would crash.